# Searching a specific bit pattern in given memory dump

Tags: c, memory, bit-manipulation, bit

I am asked to find a specific bit pattern which could have any number of bits in given memory. The bits could be spill over the byte boundary

Could someone tell me a generic logic to solve this problem using C programming?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to tell us what you have tried yourself, how did your own attempt work or not work?

Comment: Look into bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `~`, `<<` and `>>`) and start with a pencil and piece of paper.

Answer (score -1):

- Keep track of how much of the pattern you've found using a counter.
- Iterate over bytes in an outer loop.
- Iterate over bits in an inner loop.
- Look for the pattern. In case your "found counter" is zero, start from the beginning of the pattern, otherwise start at item number `[found counter]`.
- Compare the relevant bit in your pattern with the current bit in the loop.
- In case the found counter equals the length of the pattern, you can stop looking.